# Mongoose post or get a user who bought at least one item from my site every day of the week

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm creating a product for a company, and one of the feature is that they want to award any user who buys an item everyday for the 7 days of the week.
I'm currently using node, express, and mongoose.
So how do I get the records of only the users who bought at least an item everyday for the seven days of the week. This draw will be made every weekend

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your schemas or models, there are several ways you could approach this so you don't have to make a complex call every sunday for instance. Every time someone buys something and you record that, you can do a check to see if they bought something on the day before and increment a value.

For example, on your user schema, you can have a streak field like

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    index: { unique: true }
  },
  password: String,
  name: String,
  streak: Number
});
```

say sunday 7pm is when you do the draw, everyone's streak must be reset right after.
after this, what happens is that whenever someone buys something, at a minimum, you'll need to check if they've bought something on the same day before, if yes, do nothing to the streak, else add one to the streak.

come sunday, you'll need to just go look for all users with a streak of 7 and you'll  have your raffle contestants.

for sure you'd need to make sure you handle returns, cancelled orders etc but off the top this is a way i think will help you visualise the rest... plus it also saves you a complex call.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I will work on it and give a feedback. I really appreciate.

Comment: No worries, good luck

Comment: @OmegaUwedia hi, how'd you get on with this?